# Having trouble making a loop

Tags: c, sorting, loops

I'm writing a program that sorts a guest list of families, and I have everything working fine except for one part. Each family is given a priority number and along with that, the amount of people in the family that would attend the party. However, if only SOME families from a priority level can be invited and not all of them, that whole priority level is skipped and the guest list immediately stops being filled. I'm  having a bit of trouble trying to put the logic into code here.

Here's my code for that function:

```
Check_Capacity(int FAMILIES_KNOWN, int CAPACITY, int Family_Members[], int Priority[])
{
    int i, num_families = 0, num_guests = 0, count = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < FAMILIES_KNOWN; i++)
    {
        count++;

        while(Priority[i] == count)
        {
            num_guests += Family_Members[i];

            if(num_guests <= CAPACITY)
            {
                num_families++;
            }

            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return num_families;
}
```

This code results in 7 families attending the party, and 24 family members. It's supposed to be 8 families and 26 family members though. I was excited because I thought I had completed the program, but then our teacher added the fact that we have to make sure the priority levels are treated as a "whole".

In this case, FAMILIES_KNOWN is 10 and CAPACITY is 30. Here's the guest list:

```
BEN JOHNSON 4 2
DOUG ESPINOSA 3 2
SARAH TELLINGER 5 3
GRANT THOMPSON 5 2
JENNIFER WEST 7 6
JACKSON JOHNSON 1 5
MARTY MCFLY 4 1
ELIZABETH JAMES 2 6
MICKEY MOUSE 2 4
RAJ SHAH 2 5
```

The first number is the number of family members, and the second number is the priority level. Assume that I have already sorted the list by priority level. Anyone have any ideas? If you don't understand what I'm trying to do I can explain more in depth.

Comment: Try changing 'i < FAMILIES_KNOWN' to 'i <= FAMILIES_KNOWN'

Comment: Ahh I didn't think to do that lol. It did the trick, now to see if it works for more test cases.

Comment: Nvm. I had a previous version of the file open when I tried it. Doesn't do the trick :P.

Comment: As a convention don't use capitals for variable names, it is used for macros. Also I guess your function does have a return type which has been missed out here

Comment: If you invite one family from priority N but inviting all families from priority N puts you over capacity, does that mean you invite all the families from priority N or none of the families, or just those that fit within the capacity?  Is the data sorted by priority then 'nose count'?  Is the nose count increasing or decreasing within a priority?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your inner `while` loop does not increment the index, so you are only adding attendees from the first family of priority 1. Since you sort your list by priority, all you need to do in increment `i` in your `while` loop, rather than only in your `for` loop. Be careful, because this may interfere with the increment of `i` in the `for` loop.

Comment: I sort it by priority before I call Check_Capacity.

Comment: In that case, you just need to increment your `i` inside the `while` loop. I have updated my answer.

Comment: BTW, because you increment the number of families inside the inner `if` test, but the number of guests outside of it, you will always have a discrepancy between the number of families and the number of guests. You either need to do both or neither. And that's all the hints you get from the Good Doctor.

Comment: I have taught many a programming student. We want you all to solve the problems, but we **really** want you to learn to think through a problem even when you don't have a clue. These are the hints that I normally give my students when they, like you, come begging. Good luck. Make sure to bump me when you get the answer.